# My ASUS always asks me the BitLocker key

Tags: bitlocker

I have an ASUS T100TA.
I don't know what is happen, but not when I restart, Windows 10 asks me the BitLocker key. I lost my key. No problem. I can reinstall Windows. 
I created an USB drive to boot the Windows 10 installer, but my ASUS always asks me the BitLocker key! 
I tried to create an USB drive with a Linux, but my ASUS always asks me the BitLocker key! 
I tried to change in the BIOS the boot priority list where I insert only the USB drive, but my ASUS always asks me the BitLocker key! 
Help! How can I format my disk and install a new fresh Windows?

Comment: Same here. I don't really understand what happened to it. I can exit from recovery and continue to win8.1, but still I got the screen by every boot. I guess this is a windows update bug or something like that. I got this in the past few months. Before that it was okay. I'll check the Linux support for that tablet and if it is okay now I'll remove windows from it.

Comment: Try this: https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/turn-off-bitlocker-on-the-t100/

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is asking for the BitLocker key, this means the BitLocker boot loader runs. So, the most probably cause is that your computer is ignoring the USB key containing Linux. Either that USB key is not properly set up, or your computer is not configured to boot that USB key. Try the following:

1. Use another computer to test your USB key. If another computer can boot from the USB key, that means the USB key is properly set up. The best way to create a Linux USB key is using [LiveLinux USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).
2. Try the boot device selection menu! Modern computers, like mine, have a menu that allows the user to force the computer to boot from a specific device. In my case, the menu is invoked by pressing F8 during pre-boot sequence. (My computer is an ASUS P8Z68-V.) You should consult your computer's manual about the key. Use that key to force your computer to boot from the USB.
3. If everything failed, the only remaining way is to connect your hard disk to another computer and wipe it from there.

Comment: Try booting the USB key WITHOUT the bitlocker' drive connected.  If it working properly your motherboard will ask for any and all password on connected drives/devices it detects on boot up if the boots your USB mount the bitlocker' drive after a full boot from the USB and voila re install away

Comment: It's not possible to boot without the bitlocker drive becose this is a ASUS Transformer that have an internal eMMC drive.

Comment: I tried with two USB keys that work in other PC: one with the ISO of Windows 10 adn one with a Live Linux.

Comment: If I change the boot sequence in the BIOS, at the boot the system is redirected to ask me the BitLocker recovery key.
If I press the F12 and select manually the boot drive, the system is redirected to the BIOS.

Answer (score -1):

Not really familiar with ASUS, but Ive had this issue with the Motorolla Zebra Tablets I was working on. In your BIOS try to see if you the Miscellaneous TAB or look for Secure eMMc erase, not really sure for ASUS, but most hardware that has eMMc has this option in the BIOS. Goodluck